# WordPress Plugin as 'Library' From Abstract Application?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization

Here is my thought, and I could be digging myself a huge hole. That's why I'm here ;)

I am looking to develop a complex application but I want this application to run both as a standalone script as a wordpress plugin. Later I may develop into a Joomla plugin and so on.

My thought is I develop an abstract custom framework and then implement the custom functionality via extending this framework. Does that make sense?

So say `WP_Plugin` extends `My_Engine`, and then that plugin class will act as factory to manage the custom functionality in the WordPress `/lib/wordpress/` directory.

I really don't want to have to repeat myself and I would definitely be producing multiple versions of the app.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd go about this is build your standalone application but build into it a bullet proof API that will allow others and yourself leverage the power of your application.

Whichever way you look at it there will be a fair amount of coding to be done each time you visit a different CMS as they all have different ways of dealing with things. If your app has good API controls others could then make their own modules for other CMS's that you never knew existed, thus not limiting you to the likes of WordPress and Joomla.

Comment: Building a good API and letting others do the dirty work of porting to other environments can indeed be an interesting way to go!

Answer (score 1):

Extending via subclassing is possible, but it might limit your possibilities. Maybe you want to allow a third party developer extend `My_Engine` as `My_Super_Engine`, but then `WP_Plugin` would still only use `My_Engine`.

Instead, you could make `WP_Plugin` contain a reference to a concrete `My_Engine` object. This is sometimes called *"`has_a` instead or `is_a` relationship"* (`WP_Plugin` no longer is of type `My_Engine`, but it has a reference to `My_Engine` instead), or *"Dependency Injection"* (when you instantiate your `WP_Plugin` and *inject* the dependency on `My_Engine` instead of hard-coding it inside).

To give a more detailed answer it might help to have some more info on what your application is supposed to do. How much can you decouple the UI from the application logic? This will probably be the biggest hurdle in keeping the core application portable to other environments.